# How would I combine these 2 SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, dbeaver

```
select to4.ProportionOfRoute, to4.RouteID 
from tbl_operatorrouterelation to4 
where to4.operatorID = (
    select to2.operatorid 
    from tbl_operatordesc to2 
    where to2.Name = "OK Travel"
)


select tr.Frequency, tr.routeID
from tbl_route tr
where tr.routeID IN (
    select to3.RouteID 
    from tbl_operatorrouterelation to3 
    where to3.operatorID = (
        select to2.operatorid 
        from tbl_operatordesc to2 
        where to2.Name = "OK Travel"
    )
)
```

So the first one selects values from a table with multiple unique RouteID's. The second one selects values from another table with those same RouteID's.

I need to multiple the ProportionOfRoute's with the corresponding Frequency values together so this all has to be in one query.

Thanks! I've been working on this for 2 days now

Comment: You need to `INNER JOIN` the tables instead of doing separate queries. That will combine both queries and remove both of the `IN` sub-selects.

Answer (score 0):

This sequence of JOIN operations should do what you want.

```
SELECT tbl_operatorrouterelation.ProportionOfRoute, 
       tbl_route.RouteId,
       tbl_route.Frequency
  FROM tbl_operatordesc 
  JOIN tbl_operatorrouterelation 
         ON tbl_operatordesc.operatorID = tbl_operatorrouterelation.operatorID
  JOIN tbl_route 
         ON tbl_route.routeID = tbl_operatorrouterelation.routeID
 WHERE tbl_operatordesc = "OK Travel";
```

It looks like your schema (your table layout) has two [*entities*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model), `route` and `operatordesc`.  It looks like they have a [*many-to-many relationship*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) between them that's stored in your `operatorrouterelation` table: If an operator handles a route, there's a row in that table containing both the `operatorID` and the `routeID`. This means that an operator may have multiple routes, and a route may have multiple operators.

So, when you want to retrieve information about the operator called "OK Travel" including information about the routes they operate, you start with `tbl_operatordesc`. You then join it to `tbl_operatorrouterelation`, and from there you join to `tbl_route`.

I removed all the table aliases (`t02`, `t03`, ...) from my query for the sake of clarity.

**Pro tip:** As you write queries, do your best to understand the [*entity-relationship structure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) of your data. When you do understand it, it's much easier to write correct queries.